# Load MySql table from bottom to top - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, chat

Today is my first day ever messing with PHP or MySQL... I tried to make a simple chat program... it works great but it displays the old chats first and the newest chats (which are at the bottom of my table) last (at the bottom of the page).. how can I load the table in reverse order? So it displays the rows front he bottom of the database table at the top of my HTML table?

Here is my code... All in the file called "Chat.php"

```
<html><head></head><body>
<form action="chat.php" method="post">
Message: <br><textarea type="text" name="message" style="width:80%; height:300px;"></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" />
</form>

<?php

$host="****";
$user="****";
$password="****";

$cxn = mysql_pconnect ($host, $user, $password);

mysql_select_db("defaultdb", $cxn);

if (getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR)) {
    $ipaddress = getenv(HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR);
} else {
    $ipaddress = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
}

$message = $_POST["message"];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO ChatTest (ID, TimeStamp, Message) VALUES ('$ipaddress', NOW(), '$message')");

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ChatTest") or die(mysql_error()); 
 Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>ID:</th><th>TimeStamp:</th><th>Message:</th>";
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { 
 Print "<tr>"; 
    Print " <td>".$info['ID'] . "</td> "; 
    Print " <td>".$info['TimeStamp'] . " </td>";
    Print " <td>".$info['Message'] . "</td></tr>"; 
 } 
 Print "</table>"; 

mysql_close($cxn);


?>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is MySQL's [`ORDER BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) statement. You can use it to tell the DBMS in which order you want your results.

```
SELECT * FROM ChatTest
ORDER BY `TimeStamp` DESC
```

**And just another thing…**

I realize that this is your first attempt, so it's understandable that there'll be mistakes. One thing, however, you *should* learn about right away is [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Consider an example where the user's message is

```
0'); DROP TABLE ChatTest --
```

So suddenly your query would look like

```
INSERT INTO ChatTest (ID, TimeStamp, Message)
VALUES ('$ipaddress', NOW(), '0'); DROP TABLE ChatTest --')
```

To prevent this, always run user input through [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php), like this:

```
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);
```

Comment: `INSERT` doesn't have `ORDER BY` clause. You probably meant `SELECT` .

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly specify your sort key:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ChatTest ORDER BY PostDate DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Awesome! So glad it was such a simple fix! I'm still really new.. thanks O:)

Comment: $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ChatTest ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: I tried O:) It told me I had to wait 15 min I believe... anyways it is letting me now... also... Do you know how I can make the input box TextArea send the php file the HTML text with the line breaks and everything... If I enter something with line breaks and send it to my database it seems to ignore them? Would I have to use javascript to convert the text's \n to <br> then send the text to the database?

Comment: Store `\n` in your database, convert it to `<br />` when you output it with PHP's nl2br() function.